# React Native. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-context

My App was working fine and suddenly i got this error.

Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

   ```
    import { useContext } from "react";
    import jwtDecode from "jwt-decode";

    import AuthContext from "./context";
    import authStorage from "./storage";

    const useAuth = () => {
      const { user, setUser } = useContext(AuthContext);

      const logIn = (authToken) => {
        const user = jwtDecode(authToken);
        setUser(user);
        authStorage.storeToken(authToken);
      };

      const logOut = () => {
        setUser(null);
        authStorage.removeToken();
      };

      return { user, logIn, logOut };
    };

    export default useAuth;
   ```

Comment: Where do you use "useAuth" hook in your app. The code that you provided does not have any mistakes as far as I can see regarding usage of hooks. However do not try to use hooks inside of any conditions such as if-else, maybe might be helpful for your case.

Comment: @Tarık thanks a lot man it really helped me.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All looks fine. except maybe actually importing React

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
```

I know you don't need this for React from React 17, but there's no official statement from react native saying they use the new JSX compiler that doesn't require the import statement

also check the AuthContext file you imported

Comment: No, I accidentally pressed undo and the hook on the other file got moved out of the body.